# Swift Text only showing first 2 lines

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am creating a chatbot that will eventually use the ChatGPT api. Right now I am creating the chat section. I can type into the textfield and add to the array which i then display using Text() as shown in the code. However when typing a long message it will only show the 2 lines and then ... . As shown in image. How can I get it to use more than 2 lines and display it all. I have tried using lineLimit however it made no difference.

```
import SwiftUI

struct writtenpromptView: View {
    
    @State private var Prompt: String = ""

    @State var chatarray: [String] = ["Hello", "hello"]
    @State var aiarray: [String] = ["good question", "hello"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("darkgpt")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                topbar()
                    .padding(.top, 35)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(height:45)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                ScrollView {
                    ScrollViewReader { value in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            VStack {
                                ForEach(0..<chatarray.count, id:\.self) { index in
                                        Rectangle()
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("darkgpt"))
                                        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 500)
                                        .overlay(Text(chatarray[index]).foregroundColor(Color("textgrey")).frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: geometry.size.width - 60, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 500))
                                    
                                        Rectangle()
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("gptresponse"))
                                        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 500)
                                        .overlay(Text(aiarray[index]).foregroundColor(Color("textgrey")).frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: geometry.size.width - 60, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 500)
                                        )
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
                
                ZStack {
                    if Prompt == "" {
                        HStack {
                            TypingAnimationView(promptArray: ["Ask us anything...", "Explain quantum computing in simple terms.", "Write an essay on George Washington.", "Tell me a joke.", "write code to print \"hello World\" in python."], typingSpeed: 0.09, deletionSpeed: 0.09)
                        }
                    }
                        
                    TextField("", text: $Prompt)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color("textbar").opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(20))
                        .padding(.bottom, 25)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .onSubmit {
                            chatarray.append(self.Prompt)
                            aiarray.append(self.Prompt)
                            self.Prompt = ""
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct writtenpromptView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        writtenpromptView()
    }
}
```

[image: image of output when typing long message into textfield]

Comment: Not directly related to your specific problem, but take note that `ForEach(0..<chatarray.count` is dangerous and not recommended for dynamic arrays. You should use `Identifiable` items and *not* iterate over the indices.

Comment: Also, why are you using the `GeometryReader` why not just let the `View` do the layout itself?

Comment: This is my first project so I was just trying GeometryReader out.

Comment: Removing it may lead you to your solution -- you shouldn't need as many explicit frames as you have.

Comment: Instead of overlay, add background to Text view

Answer (score 0):

I made significant changes before finding the answer however even in the version posted you should be able to fix it by removing the scrollViewReader and or the geometry reader.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).